# Did C. S. Lewis support the Ransom Theory in the Chronicles of Narnia?

Tags: c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia

Some critics have claimed that the explanation of Aslan's sacrifice in *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe* supports the [ransom theory of the atonement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransom_theory_of_atonement). (**Edit:** There's also a much briefer definition of what that is [here](https://carm.org/dictionary-ransom-theory); basically, the Ransom theory holds that Christ died to provide a ransom to the Devil - it is generally rejected by Protestants, which would make it odd for C. S. Lewis to support it). However, I haven't been able to find anything in Lewis's other works to support that. Are there opinions on whether that passage *actually* supports that view, and is anyone aware of any other Lewis writings that would support (or explicitly contradict) that view?

Comment: Great question!  The ransom aspect certainly does seem to be strongly implied...

Comment: Related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45031/which-theory-of-the-atonement-did-c-s-lewis-hold

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To cite [an answer on Christinanity SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54392) that sticks to C. S. Lewis' expressed views on the matter, avoiding theological debates:

> Lewis
>
> > does not see any need to settle on a particular theory of the atonement, considering it to be something beyond human understanding.
>
> In a letter written to a "Mr. Young" (otherwise unidentified) dated 31 October 1963 -- so less than a month before he died -- Lewis is clearly replying to five specific questions that Young had asked him. One of them, #3, related to the Atonement:
>
> > 3. When Scripture says that Christ died 'for' us,<sup>a</sup> I think the word is usually ὑπέρ (on behalf of), not ἀντί (instead of). I think the ideas of sacrifice, Ransom, Championship (over Death), Substitution, etc., are all images to *suggest* the reality (not otherwise comprehensible to us) of the Atonement. To fix on any *one* of them as if it contained and limited the truth like a scientific definition wd. in my opinion be a mistake.
>
> <sub><sup>a</sup> The editor, Walter Hooper, suggests Romans 5:8 at this point.</sub>
>
> Source: C.S. Lewis, *[Collected Letters. Volume III: Narnia, Cambridge and Joy 1950-1963](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060819227)*, ed. by Walter Hooper (HarperCollins, 2007), p. 1476 [italics in original].

Credit goes to Davïd for this answer, that deals with how CSL believes his book should be read rather than with his beliefs on the subject.